# Javascript regex: split address on punctuation and beginning of number, removing punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex

I cannot figure out how to split an address where the street number comes after the street name.

Suppose the address is one of the following:

```
str='street name, 12B, 1234, The Hague, the Netherlands'
str2='street name 12B 1234AB The Hague,   the Netherlands'
str3='street name 12B 1234AB, $ ^ The Hague, the Netherlands'
```

I want to split these addresses by:

1) commas, or ideally by non-alpha/punctuation in general (e.g. ;^@). These separators should be removed;
2) number that can be followed by letters without removal.

Expected result:

```
['street name', '12B', '1234', 'The Hague', 'the Netherlands']
```

I am trying variations on str.split(/(\d+[a-zA-Z]*)/g), which still keeps elements like ", " (why?).
I also tried the OR operator | between the separators 1 and 2 but without success.
This one gets closer:

```
str.split(/(\d+[a-zA-Z]*[,])/g).map(x=>x.trim().replace(/[,.;]/g,''))
[ "street name, ", "12B,", " ", "1234,", " The Hague, the Netherlands" ]
```

Comment: Try `s.split(/\W*(?:,|(\d+[a-zA-Z]+))\W*/).filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `split`, you could also look at `match`. Here is what you get with `match` using this regular expression:

```
/\d\w*|\w+( +[a-z]\w*)*/gi
```

```js
function parts(str) {
    return str.match(/\d\w*|\w+( +[a-z]\w*)*/gi);
}

const tests = [
    'street name, 12B, 1234, The Hague, the Netherlands',
    'street name 12B 1234AB The Hague,   the Netherlands',
    'street name 12B 1234AB, $ ^ The Hague, the Netherlands'
];

for (const str of tests) console.log(parts(str));
```

Comment: awesome! So \d\w* before the | matches my point 2 (numbers that can be followed by letters). After the | there is \w+( +[a-z]\w*)* which I think matches an alphanumeric followed by spaces .. mmm let me see

Comment: Yes, the `( +[a-z\w*)` part keeps adding words to the same match as long as the added word does not start with a digit and there is no interfering punctuation.